# Парсер, запущенный на хостинге, выводит информацию на другом языке

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть парсер, который парсит название, год и жанр фильма с сайта:

https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=comedy

При запуске парсера с ПК, названия фильмов выводятся на русском языке (как я и хочу), но при запуске парсера с серверов AWS они выводятся на английском

Прикладываю нужный кусок функции:

```
headers = {'accept': accept,'user-agent': user-agent} 

def parse (base_url, headers):
movies = []
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
try:
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.select('div.lister-item.mode-advanced')
        for div in divs:
            links = div.select('a') # Читает описание после кода
            year = div.find('span', attrs = {'class': 'lister-item-year text-muted unbold'}).text
            genre = div.find('span', attrs = {'class': 'genre'}).text
            name = links[1].text if links else ''
            link = div.find('a')['href']
            link = link.replace('/?ref_=adv_li_i','')
            movies.append(name + year + genre + '\n' + 'https://imdb.com' + link)
        wtw = movies[random.randint(0,49)]
```

Попробовал засунуть в heards 'accept-language', но это не помогло, выдало ошибку

```
 ValueError: Invalid header name b'accept-language:'
```

Как сделать так, чтобы название фильма выводилось на русском языке?

Comment: попробуй так в хидере 'Accept-Language' = 'ru' раньше работало, может сейчас убрали

Comment: @user355827 большое спасибо, всё получилось! Моя ошибка была в том, что я передавал неверные значения в 'accept-language', нужно было передать 'ru-RU'.